# Why doesn't Windows have a command-line zip command?

Tags: windows, compression, zip

Windows has a built-in "zip" program for archiving and un-archiving files.  It comes with every installation of Windows, and is even integrated with the Windows Explorer GUI.

Why is there no command-line hook for this, like there is on Linux?  This seems like such a large and basic oversight.

(I am aware of 3rd party tools, I am not interested in them)

Comment: The same program that's used on Linux is also available for Windows (info-zip is not ***part*** of Linux).

Comment: See this....https://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line

Comment: as for the reason why, just Microsoft can answer. But there are a lot of ways that you can create a zip archive from command line, even without PowerShell. Cross-site duplicate: [creating batch script to unzip a file without additional zip tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21704041/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is there no command-line hook for this, like there is on Linux?

There actually is a PowerShell command you can use.  You would simply do the following command to compress a file.

```
Compress-Archive -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Example\Test FIle.txt' -DestinationPath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Example\Test.zip"
```

You would simply do the following command to uncompress that same archive.

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Example\Test.Zip" -DestinationPath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Example" -Force
```

Sources:

- [Compress-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6)
- [Expand-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6)

> (I am aware of 3rd party tools, I am not interested in them

PowerShell is built into all modern versions of Windows.  In this case the commands I am suggesting require PowerShell 5.0+

Comment: This is a great answer!  You should also post this answer on https://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line

Comment: @cowlinator - Why would I submit a question on a different community?  I am a member of this community?  This question was within scope here at Super User.  Besides, somebody already suggested PowerShell, as an answer to that question.  I don't submit a duplicate answer to a question, nor do I submit the same answer, to multiple communities.

Comment: That powershell answer is a lengthy powershell script.  Don't worry about it, I will answer it then.